# Share files between all devices in a wifi home network

Tags: windows, macos, home-networking, file-sharing

I have a Windows 10 PC, another PC with Windows 7, a MacBook Pro with OSX 10.11 and an Android phone - they are all connected to the same home wifi network.

I want to be able to transfer files between them all wirelessly, in a simple, fast and free manner.

I could use some cloud storage service (e.g., Drive or DropBox), which would be ok, but I'd like direct transfer, rather than having to store my files in the cloud...

To share files between the two Windows PCs only, I use the Home Group functionality, and I wanted something like that, but allowing sharing with OSX as well (and optionally with Android, although that's not required).

Which would be my best option?

Comment: My router has a usb jack with the idea that you add your own hard drive or large flash drive.  That storage space is available always for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Syncthing. It is completely free and open source + it works for almost all platforms.

https://syncthing.net

Comment: [Don't leave signatures in your answers in the future per the help center.](http://superuser.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just share files between Windows, [OSX](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204445) and [Android](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-free-android-apps-for-easy-smb-connection/).

Comment: This does not really answer the author question since it does not explain HOW to do it.

Answer (score 0):

OS X ships with a dependable SFTP client & server, which are secure alternatives to FTP. Android can load AndFTP (SFTP client and more) and Windows can load PSFTP, from the respected author of PuTTY.